# My .zshrc file is executed twice each time, what are the possible reasons?

Tags: linux, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I set zsh theme to "random" but I found that everytime I open a new WSL window the theme will change twice, which means **my `.zshrc` file was executed twice every time.**

I am using **WSL2** now and I am also using **oh my zsh**.

I tried `source .zshrc` and the theme only changed once so I think the file itself maybe not the problem.

My `.zprofile` file is empty.

I am wondering how can I find the reason and what is the solution.

BTW, here is my `.zshrc` file

```bash
zmodload zsh/zprof

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="random"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
          z
          git 
          extract
          command-not-found
        )

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"


export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

alias fd=fdfind
alias goplantuml=~/go/bin/goplantuml

[[ -e ~/.profile ]] && emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile'

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/jiang/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/jiang/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/jiang/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/jiang/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

setopt no_nomatch

### Added by Zinit's installer
if [[ ! -f $HOME/.local/share/zinit/zinit.git/zinit.zsh ]]; then
    print -P "%F{33} %F{220}Installing %F{33}ZDHARMA-CONTINUUM%F{220} Initiative Plugin Manager (%F{33}zdharma-continuum/zinit%F{220})鈥?f"
    command mkdir -p "$HOME/.local/share/zinit" && command chmod g-rwX "$HOME/.local/share/zinit"
    command git clone https://github.com/zdharma-continuum/zinit "$HOME/.local/share/zinit/zinit.git" && \
        print -P "%F{33} %F{34}Installation successful.%f%b" || \
        print -P "%F{160} The clone has failed.%f%b"
fi

source "$HOME/.local/share/zinit/zinit.git/zinit.zsh"
autoload -Uz _zinit
(( ${+_comps} )) && _comps[zinit]=_zinit

# Load a few important annexes, without Turbo
# (this is currently required for annexes)
zinit light-mode for \
    zdharma-continuum/zinit-annex-as-monitor \
    zdharma-continuum/zinit-annex-bin-gem-node \
    zdharma-continuum/zinit-annex-patch-dl \
    zdharma-continuum/zinit-annex-rust

### End of Zinit's installer chunk

# Plugin history-search-multi-word loaded with investigating.
zinit load zdharma-continuum/history-search-multi-word

# Two regular plugins loaded without investigating.
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light zdharma-continuum/fast-syntax-highlighting

zinit ice from"gh-r" as"program"
zinit light junegunn/fzf

export PATH=$PATH:~/go/bin

eval $(thefuck --alias --enable-experimental-instant-mode)
```

And here is my `.profile` file.

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ]; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

# export NEMU_HOME=/home/jiang/LocalLearning/OS/ics2022/nemu
# export AM_HOME=/home/jiang/LocalLearning/OS/ics2022/abstract-machine

#ln -s /usr/bin/ccache /usr/local/bin/gcc
#ln -s /usr/bin/ccache /usr/local/bin/g++
#ln -s /usr/bin/ccache /usr/local/bin/cc
#ln -s /usr/bin/ccache /usr/local/bin/c++

alias vi='nvim'
alias vim='nvim'

pkill lsyncd
lsyncd -log Exec ~/Documents/Config/lsyncd.conf.lua >/dev/null

. "$HOME/.cargo/env"

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: What is in your `.profile` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment before, I comment the line `[[ -e ~/.profile ]] && emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile'` and it works well again.

Comment: Yes you dont need to source `.profile`. It is already automatically sourced

Comment: My first guess is that either `eval "$__conda_setup"` or further down `. "/home/jiang/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"`creates a new zsh process. Not familiar with conda, so I can't say for sure. You would have to trace it (`set -x`).

Comment: Ah, and for the safe side, also check `. "$HOME/.cargo/env"`.